# Using the object of a `With` statement as parameter for a procedure call

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to use the object of a `With` statement as parameter for a procedure called from within a `With` block, without having to fully qualify that object? It could be the equivalent of a `this` or `me`.

```
With thisThing.thatThing.otherThing.myObject
    MySub [?] ' How do I specify myObject as the parameter?
    MySub This 'No, that's not it...
    MySub Me  'Not this either... what is it?

    'Of course I could do this:
    MySub  thisThing.thatThing.otherThing.myObject
    'But I'd prefer not having to fully qualify myObject like that
    ....
End With
```

**Example :**

```
With Worksheet.Range("A1:E4")
    Call SubName(<range from with>)
End With
```

`<range from with>` would be referring to `Worksheet.Range("A1")`

**Edit:**

Seems that I was implying a single value by giving a range of just a single cell range, my bad. I'm specifically trying to parse a range into the procedure that I'm calling (it draws some borders around the specified range).

My actual code:

```
With ReportSheet
    // Call drawBorder(.Range(.Cells(j + 9, 2), .Cells(k + 9, 2))) <--What I have to do right now
    With .Range(.Cells(j + 9, 2), .Cells(k + 9, 2))
        //Call drawBorder(<the specified range above> <--What I want to do
        //Other code
    End With
End With

Sub drawBorder(drawRange As Range)
    With drawRange
       //Various code
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 I have asked myself the same question countless times. Though I'm afraid [I have only bad news for you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19700906/119775).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
drawBorder .Cells
```

Note: no need to use `Call`, the `Sub` name on its own followed by unbracketed parameters is sufficient

Answer (score 1):

I see what you are getting at, but unfortunately there is no way to directly do what you are asking. One weakness of the `With` statement is exactly what you are pointing to: when you say `With myObject`, you can easily refer to `myObject`'s children methods and properties, but there is no way to indirectly refer to `myObject` itself.

That may be why the `With` statement has not caught on beyond Visual Basic. In other languages, this would be the standard way of doing it:

```
Dim rng as Range
'...
With ReportSheet
    '...
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(j + 9, 2), .Cells(k + 9, 2))
    With rng
        DrawBorder rng ' can also move this outside With block if you prefer
        .DoThis
        .DoThat
        '...
    End With        
End With
```

i.e. set an explicit reference to the object you are interested in, and use that thenceforth.