# VBA "With object" syntax - can you refer to the object itself?

Tags: vba

I often use the With object syntax when I'm doing a bunch of different stuff with an object. It's useful shorthand for calling the object's properties/methods without having to clutter up the code reusing the object's name. However sometimes I want to call a function which takes as an argument the object itself. Is there any way to refer to the object in that case?

```
' Class Module
' Class1

' Code Module
Sub f(byref obj as Class1)
End Sub

Sub test()
  Dim obj as Class1: set obj = new Class1
  With obj
    f Me ' Doesn't work - can you refer to obj in this context?
    f obj ' Works but I don't like it when the object has a long name
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It depends on the type. Your example was only for a class. For a range, you can use .cells (see 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19698651/using-the-object-of-a-with-statement-as-parameter-for-a-procedure-call)

Answer (score 3):

No, there is not.  You just have to use the object itself, as you have done in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old posting but I thought this might help others that search for a solution. Actually, there is a slight workaround for this that I have used.  It isn't as nice as having something like "Me" (that doesn't work here) but it can help.

You can use the set statement to assign the object to a temporary variable that you can use inside the With statement as in the following example (using your original example above):

`set s= obj
with s
  f s
end with`

The variable s can be any shorter name you wish since it acts like a variable. When you have a large object specification in place of obj, this comes in handy.  Hope this helps someone.